# Unable to set timeout value on java observable not working

Tags: android, timeout, observable, subscribe

I am using Android studio 2.3.3 to develop an app.

I am using Observable to make rest api calls.
It gets timeout after around 10 seconds while my server takes 20 seconds to process and respond.

I tried to set timeout value as in code snippet below. But still its getting timed out at around 10 seconds.

```
goalService.saveGoal(appState.getUserId(), goal)
                    .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Goal>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            inProgress = false;
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            if (isViewAttached()) {
                                getView().hideLoader();
                                handleError(e);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Goal goal) {
                         }
```

It hit the onError method with java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

How can I figure out the exact reason for timeout ?
How can I set the timeout value for this case ?

Answer (score 2):

use timer task:

```
TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ...
                    }
                };
                new Timer().schedule(doAsynchronousTask, (your needed seconds * 1000));
```